# unexpected token illegal error when dynamically adding html content

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the following json from a rest webservice. -

```
[
{
    "jobId": 1000160829,
    "jobRefID": "Blue Shields key hospital contract negotiations using robust analytic tools and analyses--strategic contract roadmap, negotiation factsheets, and&hellip;",
    "companyName": "Blue Shield Of California",
    "jobTitle": "Senior Manger, Business Analysis",
}]
```

I have the following code to use this data and generate dynamic html content -

```
htmlAdd += '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
            for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                htmlAdd += '<li><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/companies/opentable.png" alt="" />';
                htmlAdd += '</div><div class="col-lg-10"><ul align="left" class="list-unstyled">';
                htmlAdd += '<li><h4><a href="#">'+data[i].jobTitle+'&#8212;</a></h4>;
                htmlAdd += '</li><li>'+data[i].companyName+'&#8212;'+data[i].city+', '+data[i].state+'&nbsp;<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></a></li>';
                htmlAdd += '<li class="digest">&#183; '+data[i].jobDescription+'<a href="#">details</a></li>;
                htmlAdd += '</ul></div></div></li>;
                htmlAdd += '<li><hr/></li>';
            }
           htmlAdd += '</ul>;
           document.getElementById('jobListing').innerHTML = htmlAdd;
```

The same static code works -

```
<div class="content">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/companies/opentable.png" alt="" /> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <ul align="left" class="list-unstyled">
                <li>
                  <h4><a href="#">Senior Software Engineer &#8212; Data Science team</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li class="digest">&#183; Rapidly develop proof-of-concept prototypes to prove out hypotheses 
                  &#183; Design, architect, implement, and debug robust, high-volume production...&nbsp;<a href="#">details</a></li>
                <li class="digest"><a href="#">Overview</a> | <a href="#">Reviews</a> | <a href="#">Salaries</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <hr/>
        </li>
```

Anyone knows where is the mistake?

Comment: As is apparent from the syntax highlighting, you've forgotten a few string delimiters in your js code.

Comment: Slash "/" is "elegal" - you have to escape it.

Comment: @madflow: Uh, what? Where is it illegal?

Comment: @Bergi In my brain obviously...

Answer (score 0):

The following should help since your original code was lacking matching apostrophes (')

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    htmlAdd += '<li><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/companies/opentable.png" alt="" />';
    htmlAdd += '</div><div class="col-lg-10"><ul align="left" class="list-unstyled">';
    htmlAdd += '<li><h4><a href="#">'+data[i].jobTitle+'&#8212;</a></h4>';
    htmlAdd += '</li><li>'+data[i].companyName+'&#8212;'+data[i].city+', '+data[i].state+'&nbsp;<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></a></li>';
    htmlAdd += '<li class="digest">&#183; '+data[i].jobDescription+'<a href="#">details</a></li>';
    htmlAdd += '</ul></div></div></li>';
    htmlAdd += '<li><hr/></li>';
}
htmlAdd += '</ul>';
```

fix your apostrophys

Comment: They are also missing an apostrophe on this line: htmlAdd += '</ul></div></div></li>;

Comment: Not to forget `htmlAdd += '</ul>;`…

Comment: edited the answer, yeh I caught a few more after I posted it.